# How do i add the class to the input element of adjacent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
($(this).addClass("error")
```

adds the class error to select upon validation.
But along with it i also want to add this class to the input field inside next `<span>`.
This is am doing to solve my problem stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080639/unable-to-add-class-in-input-of-select2-upon-validation). I think it can be done like this.

Following is the html where i want to add the `class="error"`

```
<select data-placeholder="Pick the ones that apply to you" multiple="" class="js-selection select2-hidden-accessible error" name="option" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-required="true" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" placeholder="Please fill out this field">
                        <option selected="" value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
                        <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
                        <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>

<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: auto;">
 <span class="selection">
   <span aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" role="combobox" class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" tabindex="0">
     <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
       <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
          <input type="search" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" class="select2-search__field" placeholder="Pick the ones that apply to you" style="width: 0px;">
       </li>
     </ul>
    </span>
 </span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown-wrapper"></span></span>
```

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked earlier?

Comment: @Barmar yup you are right but i thought  that question was not clear may be, so  i thought if i get the solution to add the class to input of adjacent element, then the problem is solved

Comment: Edit your question , don't create a new one. Seems very similar also to a question you asked 2 days ago and got an answer to where the answer showed you how to target a specific sibling. look at the traverse methods in jQuery API

Comment: If you are trying to get the adjacent element, as in sibling, in JavaScript, use `Node.nextSibling`. Then you can add the class with `Element.classList.add("error");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation `this` is the `select`, so you can do it this way:

```
$(this).addClass('error');
$(this).next().find('input').addClass('error');
```

You can combine them too into one operation using `add()`:

```
$(this).add($(this).next().find('input')).addClass('error');
```